# Node.js not executing nested for loop correctly as it is asynchronous

Tags: node.js

```
let data = {};
sql.query("SELECT * FROM courses WHERE name = ?", [name], function(err, course) {
  if (err) result(null, err);
  else {
    data.id = course[0].id;
    data.course = course[0].name;
    data.terms = []

    sql.query("SELECT * FROM terms WHERE course_id = ?", [course[0].id], function(err, term) {
      if (err) result(null, err);
      else {
        for (let i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
          data.terms.push({
            id: term[i].id,
            name: term[i].name,
            modules: []
          });
          sql.query("SELECT * FROM modules WHERE term_id = ?", [term[i].id], function(err, module) {
            if (err) result(null, err);
            else {
              for (let j = 0; j < module.length; j++) {
                data.terms[i].modules.push({
                  id: module[j].id,
                  name: module[j].name,
                  topics: []
                });
                sql.query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE module_id = ?", [module[j].id], function(err, topic) {
                  if (err) result(null, err);
                  else {
                    for (let k = 0; k < topic.length; k++) {
                      data.terms[i].modules[j].topics.push({
                        id: topic[k].id,
                        name: topic[k].name
                      });
                    }
                    if (i === term.length - 1) result(null, data);
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Aware of arrow functions, replace all functions i.e. `function (){}` with `(//arguments ) => { //function body }`

Comment: I have done that, but nothing happen.

Comment: I regret to inform you that this is a classic example of "callback hell" and all asynchronous operations should be converted to promises and then the whole thing can be written much more cleanly with promises, `.then()/.catch()` and `async/await`.  But, the first step is to convert all your asynchronous operations to use promises and then you can use promise control-flow to manage the asynchronous flow.  FYI, there is a different version of mysql that has promise support built-in.

Comment: Can you written in that way, because when I was trying to do that I was confusing in indexing. As you can see that I am using specific array position while inserting data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous node js "For" loop with database query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984072/asynchronous-node-js-for-loop-with-database-query)

Comment: there are many, many Stack Overflow questions regarding asynchronous node.js functions inside of `for` loops. which of them have you researched and attempted and why did they not solve your particular problem?

Comment: No, they didn't solve.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Bluebird package. Here is the link to npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird Have you tried it before?

Also you can see the oficial docs page here http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

Here is an snippet from some project that I was working on recently. I'll paste it here as an example.

Inside a while loop Bluebird iterates over a collection of players and wait (one second) before moving to the next array item:

Don't forget to import bluebird first: `const Promise = require('bluebird');`

```
while(someCondition) {
  await Promise.each(players, async (p) => {
    const team = this.getTeamByPlayer(p);
    logger.info(`[${team.name}] ${p.nombre} is making a move`);
    p.jugar();
    await this.wait(1000);
  })
 }
```

> `this.wait(n)`is a class method that implements an async timeout

As you can see I'm using async/await over the iteration and inside the loop as well.

Bluebird also has a `Promisify` method that can help you to write code in a "async/await" way making your code clearest!

Let me know if you have any question!

Hope it helps!

Lucas.-